# Compare and check out differences between two dataframes using pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's suppose that we have a dataframe with the following schema

```
    root
     |-- AUTHOR_ID: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |-- Books: array (nullable = false)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
     |    |    |-- BOOK_ID: integer (nullable = false)
     |    |    |-- Chapters: array (nullable = true) 
     |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- NAME: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- NUMBER_PAGES: integer (nullable = true)
```

As you can see, we nested struct objects

- How can we compare  two dataframes with the same schema and calculate or bring out the **deltas**(differences) ?

Let's suppose that the following changes are occured:

- the name of the first chapter of book with **id=1** was changed, thus we can imagine the following comparison output

```
{
    "AUTHOR_ID": 1,
    "Books": [
        {
            "BOOK_ID": 1,
            "Chapters": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "NAME": {
                      "before": "Etranger",
                      "after": "L'étranger"
                    }      
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:** we will show only the **Ids** and the changed values for the relevant items

Comment: Hi @Smaillns, can you clarify your question by adding simple input and expected output? It's not clear how you want to compare and differences you want to show in your output.

Comment: Could you add examples to demonstrate how you want the delta to be represented?  ie: if NAME is changed "abcd" to "badce", NUMBER_PAGES is changed 10 to 100, one element within the Books array is changed, how it should be represented?  It depends on how you want to use the output, so I don't think I can define it for you.

Comment: You should join both the dataframes on "AuthorID" and then use a UDF to figure out the differences among the books by ordering the list of books on bookId and the iterating through the list.

Comment: the subtract function of Spark do a great job so far !    `diff = current_df.subtract(ref_df)`

Comment: what did you end up choosing?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code to join by authorId and then compare.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_list, struct, col
from operator import itemgetter
from  pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructType, StringType, StructField

# construct data

data = [('AA_1',  'S1', "10", "1", "Introduction to Quadratic Equation"),
        ('AA_1',  'S1', "10", "2", "Fundamentals"),
        ('AA_1',  'S1', "11", "1", "Preface"),
        ('AA_1',  'S1', "11", "2", "Wading in to the waters"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "100", "1", "Introduction"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "100", "2", "Fundamentals"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "110", "1", "Prologue"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "110", "2", "Epilogue"),
]

data2  = [('AA_1',  'S1', "10", "1", "Introduction to Linear Algebra"),
        ('AA_1',  'S1', "10", "2", "Fundamentals"),
        ('AA_1',  'S1', "11", "1", "Preface"),
        ('AA_1',  'S1', "11", "2", "Wading in to the waters"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "100", "1", "Introduction"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "100", "2", "Fundamentals2"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "110", "1", "Prologue"),
        ('AA_2',  'S2', "110", "2", "Epilogue"),
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["authorId", "name", "bookId", "chapterId", "chapterName"]).groupBy(['authorId', 'name', 'bookId']).agg(collect_list(struct("chapterId", "chapterName")).alias("chapters")).groupBy(['authorId', 'name']).agg(collect_list(struct('bookId', 'chapters')).alias('books'))

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ["authorId", "name", "bookId", "chapterId", "chapterName"]).groupBy(['authorId', 'name', 'bookId']).agg(collect_list(struct("chapterId", "chapterName")).alias("chapters")).groupBy(['authorId', 'name']).agg(collect_list(struct('bookId', 'chapters')).alias('books'))

df2 = df2.select(col('authorId').alias('authorId2'),col('name').alias('name2'), col('books').alias('books2') )

# join on authorId
df3 = df.join(df2, [df.authorId == df2.authorId2])


# UDF to compare, needs additional checks on books and chapters lengths and Null checks

@udf(ArrayType(StructType([StructField("bookId", StringType()), StructField("chapters", ArrayType(StructType([StructField("chapterId", StringType()), StructField("name", StructType([StructField("before", StringType()), StructField("after", StringType())]))])))])))                                  
def get_book_diff(b1, b2):
  if (len(b1) != len(b2)):
    return None
  b1.sort(key = itemgetter('bookId'))
  b2.sort(key = itemgetter('bookId'))
  list_data = []
  i=0
  for book in b1:
    data = {}
    if book.bookId == b2[i].bookId:
      data['bookId']=book.bookId
      book.chapters.sort(key = itemgetter('chapterId'))
      b2[i].chapters.sort(key = itemgetter('chapterId'))
      data['chapters']=[]
      j=0
      for chap in book.chapters:
        if chap.chapterId == b2[i].chapters[j].chapterId:
          if chap.chapterName != b2[i].chapters[j].chapterName:
            data['chapters'].append({'chapterId':chap.chapterId, 'name': {"before": chap.chapterName, "after": b2[i].chapters[j].chapterName}})
        j+=1
    i+=1  
    list_data.append(data)  
    
  return list_data
        
  
df3 = df3.withColumn('book_diff', get_book_diff('books', 'books2'))

#df3.select('authorId', 'book_diff').show(truncate=False)
display(df3.select('authorId', 'book_diff'))
```

Comment: Looks like this would work appreciate seeing the code for the approach but I have a feeling it would be slow.

Comment: Yeah, another way to do would be to explode the book data and make it look like data, data2  (basically reverse of the data set up above). Then perform the comparison. It would not have involved udfs and therefore be more performant. Edited: Oh!  which is what you have suggested in your answer. :)

Comment: It would be interesting to run a test to see at want points which algorithm is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think here the unfortunate requirement is we need to flatten the struct into columns to allow comparison.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
columns = ["AUTHOR_ID","NAME","Books"] # lazy partial naming

#Original
data = [(1, "James,,Smith",[(1,[(1,"The beggining", 12, "It was a great day")])]), (2, "Stephen King", [(2,[(1,"The start", 12, "It was a great day")])])]
#Update
# Bookid 1 --> added a chapter, fixed a typo in the first chapter. 
# Bookid 2 -->  Changed nothing 
data_after = [(1, "James,,Smith",[(1,[(1,"The begining", 12, "It was a great day"),(2,"The end", 1, "It was a great night")])]), (2, "Stephen King", [(2,[(1,"The start", 12, "It was an a great day")])])]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data_after,schema=columns)

#flatten the struct into columns Could have use withColumn.
df_flat = df.select("*", F.posexplode(F.col("Books")).alias("pos","Book")).select( "*", F.col("Book._1").alias("BookId"), F.posexplode(F.col("Book._2")).alias("pos","Chapter") ).select("*", F.col("Chapter.*"), F.lit("Original").alias("source") );
df2_flat = df2.select("*", F.posexplode(F.col("Books")).alias("pos","Book")).select( "*", F.col("Book._1").alias("BookId"), F.posexplode(F.col("Book._2")).alias("pos","Chapter") ).select("*", F.col("Chapter.*"), F.lit("Update").alias("source") );
#use a union to pull all data together
all = df_flat.union(df2_flat).withColumnRenamed("_1", "Chapter_id")\
.withColumnRenamed("_2", "text")
#Find things that don't have a match these are the additions/updates/deletion
all.groupBy("AUTHOR_ID","BookId","Chapter_id","text").agg(F.first("source"),F.count("text").alias("count")).where(F.col("count") != 2).show()



+---------+------+----------+-------------+--------------------+-----+
|AUTHOR_ID|BookId|Chapter_id|         text|first(source, false)|count|
+---------+------+----------+-------------+--------------------+-----+
|        1|     1|         2|      The end|              Update|    1|
|        1|     1|         1| The begining|              Update|    1|
|        1|     1|         1|The beggining|            Original|    1|
+---------+------+----------+-------------+--------------------+-----+
```

From here you need to do a little more work. (Think 1 more groupBy down to the Author/Bookid/chapterid, (count the chapterid) then select [with/otherwise] logic on source)

- If a chapter exists in the Update and Original it's an edit. (count of 2)
- Only exists in Update it's addition.  (count of 1)
- Only exists in Original it's a deletion.  (count of 1)

Building back to your struct back from here is up to you, but I think this demonstrates the idea of what's required.  Using the page number of the chapter might actually be a good method to detect change.  It's certainly cheaper than comparing strings likely not as accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
from gresearch.spark.diff import *
left.diff(right)
```

See https://github.com/G-Research/spark-extension/blob/master/DIFF.md